WS_EX_TOPMOST seemingly does nothing
I've got a pyglet Window subclass that got this in his __init__ function. Every flag works but WS_EX_TOPMOST.
hwnd = self._hwnd # type: ignore

GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080
WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008
LWA_COLORCODE = 0x1

ex_style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ex_style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST)
windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, LWA_COLORCODE)
windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002)

Full __init__ code is a complete mess, but I'll provide it too to prevent any misunderstandings.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Overriding something for beauty's sake
        kwargs['style'] = 'borderless'
        kwargs['width'] = bg_img.width
        kwargs['height'] = screen.height
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Doing some unusual low-level gibberish to explain Windows how our pyglet app should behave and look like
        hwnd = self._hwnd # type: ignore
        GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
        WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000
        WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080
        WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008
        LWA_COLORCODE = 0x1
        ex_style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
        windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ex_style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST)
        windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, LWA_COLORCODE)
        windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002)

        self.set_location(screen.width - self.width, 0)

        self.shown = True

        self.cursors = {
            'default': self.get_system_mouse_cursor(Window.CURSOR_DEFAULT),
            'hand': self.get_system_mouse_cursor(Window.CURSOR_HAND)
        }

        # omelette w/ bacon
        self.batch = Batch()
        self.bg = Sprite(bg_img, batch = self.batch)


"Every flag works but WS_EX_TOPMOST"" - in what way, exactly? You need to be more specific

@RemyLebeau, no effect, as if it wasn't present.

The WS_EX_TOPMOST extended style is used to make a window always appear on top of all other windows.
However, setting WS_EX_TOPMOST alone does not automatically bring the window to the top of the Z-order. You also need to specify the window position using SetWindowPos, so you need to ensure the window is topmost by updating this part of your code:
    .....
        # new styles
        windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, ex_style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST)
        windll.user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, LWA_COLORCODE)

        # topmost window
        HWND_TOPMOST = -1
        SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001
        SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
        windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
    .....


"to make a window always appear on top of all other windows [...]" - The WS_EX_TOPMOST style doesn't do that. It merely places the window in front of non topmost windows. It can still be obscured by another topmost window. In addition there are "bands" that serve as a higher-order Z order. It's what makes the Start Menu or Task Manager appear in front of topmost windows. Bands are undocumented and have no public API.

WS_EX_TOPMOST only ensures your window is above any which do not have the topmost, but does not bring to a system privileged layer such as the Start Menu, or Task Manager.That type of behavior depends upon undocumented features and is unsupported in the Windows API.

Desktop bands aren't "privileged". Any application can register into any band they decide, making the WS_EX_TOPMOST style rather useless. Relying on semantics it does not provide is wrong regardless.
